# ng2-pdfjs-viewer onDocumentLoad not triggered

Tags: angular, pdf.js, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I need to run a method when the pdf document is loaded. But the onDocumentLoad callback is not getting triggered. I'm rendering the pdf in the same window.

```
<div id="viewer">
    <ng2-pdfjs-viewer #pdfViewer viewerId="viewerId" (onDocumentLoad)="documentLoaded($event)" [showSpinner]="showSpinner"></ng2-pdfjs-viewer>    
</div>
```

Comment: When exactly do you want to run function ?

Comment: after the pdf is rendered

Comment: make sure spelling of this method `documentLoaded($event)` inside your component.ts file is also the same.

Comment: It's the same in the component. Not sure why it's not getting fired.

Comment: How you set PDF path in component ?

Comment: `@Input()
  set fileObject(pdfFile: any) {
    if (pdfFile != undefined) {
      this._pdfViewer.pdfSrc = pdfFile;
      this._pdfViewer.refresh();     
    }
  };`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240431/discussion-between-grd-and-sanjay-rawat).